# subscribing to a zipped Observable not going to onNext

Tags: rx-java

I have 3 observables:

1. getToppingsObservable returns an Observable
2. getDrinksObservable returns an Observable
3. getStoreObservable returns an Observable

the 3 observables are independent of one another but I want to update a view after all 3 have completed without nesting an observable in onCompleted.

I zipped the observables:

```
    Observable.zip(getToppingsObservable(), 
                   getDrinksObservable(),
                   getStoreObservable, 
                   new Function3<Topping, Drink, Store>() {
                   @Override
                   public void apply(Topping topping, Drink drink, 
                   Store store) {
                       selectedTopping = topping;
                       selectedDrink = drink;
                       selectedStore = store;
                   }
```

Upon subscribing to this observable apply is invoked twice but neither onNext nor onError is.  Am I incorrectin choosing zip?

Comment: The problem was that inside apply I return null.  This prevents onNext(Object o) from being called.  If I return selectedTopping it gets called.  Since the return value isn't important, is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Why don't you return a dummy value just to proceed with your stream?